# Android Studio emulator giving list of errors

Tags: android-studio

I have a fresh install of android studio and created an emulator with API 27 for a Nexus 6.  On the first time trying to launch it, I got a list of errors and upon trying again, I got a similar list like so:

[image]

Does anybody know what may be causing this?  I am running it on a Linux install.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing the following package:

```
libstdc++5
```

and then running these commands:

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++ 
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
```